# BinaryFormatter.Serialize not working

Tags: c#, serialization, unity-game-engine

I am trying to serialize an object into a binary file. I am using BinaryFormatter.Serialize to serialize the object, but when I try to call it, I get a parser error on the stream argument, "Unexpected symbol `(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration".

This is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

public class Serializer{
    Properties prop = new Properties ();
    IFormatter f = new BinaryFormatter();
    Stream s = new FileStream("Properties/prop.bin", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
    f.Serialize(s, prop);
    s.Close();
}
```

The error is on:

```
f.Serialize(s, prop); //the error is on the 's'
```

and I am getting the same error here:

```
s.Close();
```

How can I fix these errors?

Here is what I am serializing:

```
public class Properties{
    public string y = "2";
    public string x = "4";
}
```

Comment: what are you serializing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code needs to be inside a function.

```
public class Serializer{

    public void Seralize()
    {
        Properties prop = new Properties ();
        IFormatter f = new BinaryFormatter();
        Stream s = new FileStream("Properties/prop.bin", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
        f.Serialize(s, prop);
        s.Close();
    }

}
```

However I would recommend you avoid `BinaryFormatter` assembly version changes can easily break your file, use XML or some other binary formatter instead.

Comment: I am so stupid, thank you. Recommend any other serializers? I am very new to them, and can't seem to find any information for beginners for serializers.

Comment: If you are a beginner I would reccomend you just stick with [XmlSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx). It will be a little bigger file but it is more forgiving when stuff goes wrong or you change versions.

Comment: As for information, just [check out the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh(v=vs.110).aspx).